# How to connect two clients to one server in python?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, server, client

I am trying to connect two clients, to my server. My present code is written for one client to server connection. What I basically want is that Client_1 will send messages to the server, and server can send messages back to Client_1. The messages that Client_1 will send to the server, will just get replicated or mirrored in Client_2. Client_2 itself shall not have the capability of sending messages to the server. It should only get the message displayed that Client_1 sends to the server. Below I am sharing the server code, Client_1 code, Client_2 code.

Server code

```
import socket


def server_program():

    # get the hostname
    host = socket.gethostname()
    port = 5000  # initiate port no above 1024
    server_socket = socket.socket()  # get instance
    # look closely. The bind() function takes tuple as argument
    server_socket.bind((host, port))  # bind host address and port together

    # configure how many client the server can listen simultaneously
    server_socket.listen(2)
    conn, address = server_socket.accept()  # accept new connection
    print("Connection from: " + str(address))
    while True:
        # receive data stream. it won't accept data packet greater than 1024 bytes
        data = conn.recv(1024).decode()
        if not data:
            # if data is not received break
            break
        print("from connected user: " + str(data))
        data = input(' -> ')
        conn.send(data.encode())  # send data to the client

    conn.close()  # close the connection


if __name__ == '__main__':
    server_program()
```

Client_1 code

```
import socket


def client_program():
    host = socket.gethostname()  # as both code is running on same pc
    port = 5000  # socket server port number

    client_socket = socket.socket()  # instantiate
    client_socket.connect((host, port))  # connect to the server

    message = input(" -> ")  # take input

    while message.lower().strip() != 'bye':
        client_socket.send(message.encode())  # send message
        data = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()  # receive response

        print('Received from server: ' + data)  # show in terminal

        message = input(" -> ")  # again take input

    client_socket.close()  # close the connection


if __name__ == '__main__':
    client_program()
```

Client_2 code

```
import socket


def client_program():

    # get the hostname
    host = socket.gethostname()
    port = 5000  # initiate port no above 1024
    client_socket = socket.socket() # get instance

    client_socket.connect((host, port))      # get connected to the server                           

    #server_socket.bind((host, port))  # bind host address and port together

    while message.lower().strip() !='bye':
     client_socket.send(message.encode())  # send message
     data = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()  # receive response

     print('Received from server: ' + data)  # show in terminal

    client_socket.close()  # close the connection



if __name__ == '__main__':
    client_program()
```

How shall I modify the server code as well as the Client_2 code to achieve the desired objective. At present When I run the Client_2 code I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "socket_MobileUnit_client.py", line 26, in <module>
    client_program()   File "socket_MobileUnit_client.py", line 11, in client_program
    client_socket.connect((host, port))      # get connected to the server                            ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

Comment: I asked a similar question some two weeks ago, here and on reddit, but nobody answered. What I wanted to do was to have a simple chat between multiple clients. I found code that allows for it, but if Client1 sends the message, Client2 will not receive it until Client2 sends a message of its own. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60761450/im-looking-for-a-working-example-of-a-python-socket-multi-client-chat

Comment: You have one code for two clients?

Comment: The link for GitHub repository for this project is given :

https://github.com/Sayantan4796/Garbage-Management